# Как получить uint из RGB

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Код конвертации `uint` цвета в RGB:

```
uint pixel = GetPixel(hDC, x, y);
byte r = (byte)(pixel & 0x000000FF);
byte g = (byte)((pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
byte b = (byte)((pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
```

Интересует как произвести обратное действие. Т.е. как из RGB получить `uint`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint pixel = r | (g << 8) | (b << 16) | (a << 24)
```

Только аккуратно с переполнением (r,g,b должны быть int).

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло. Когда же я уже начну понимать эту телегу)

Comment: Только, я так понимаю, надо явно привести `int`, получаемый в правой части выражения, к `uint`.

Comment: @Regent да вроде бы само приводит. Я к С++ больше  привык. Поэтому не уверен.

Comment: Я протестировал код - VS таки сказала привести.

Comment: int pixel = 0;
            int r = color.R;
            int g = color.G;
            int b = color.B;
            pixel = r | (g << 8) | (b << 16);

Вот так сделал. С приведением могу разобраться)